# Remove parent object and child object if value is undefined using Array.filter(?)

Tags: javascript, arrays

### **Question:**

**How can I removal all `emailAddress` that are empty, and if there are no `emailAddresses` for an approval, remove that approval too.**

My current solution will remove approvals when emailAddress completely empty. But not when two emailAddresses are present and one is empty (see script output vs. expected output)

```js
var request = {
 approvals: [
     {
       type: 'media',
       emailAddresses: [
        {emailAddress: 'frank@gmail.com'},
       ]
     },
     {
       type: 'other',
       emailAddresses: [
        {emailAddress: ''},
       ]
     },
     {
       type: 'scope',
       emailAddresses: [
        {emailAddress: 'kelly@yahoo.com'},
        {emailAddress: ''},
       ]
     }
   ] 
}
const filterOutEmptyEmails = (approval) => {
  if(approval.emailAddresses.filter(x => !!x.emailAddress).length){
    return true;  
  }
  
}

let output = request.approvals.filter(filterOutEmptyEmails);

console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
```

```
// EXPECTED OUTPUT:
// approval: [
//     {
//       type: 'media',
//       emailAddresses: [
//         {emailAddress: 'frank@gmail.com'},
//       ]
//     },
//     {
//       type: 'scope',
//       emailAddresses: [
//         {emailAddress: 'kelly@yahoo.com'},
//       ]
//     }
//   ] 
// }]
```

### [Live Code](https://repl.it/EbTQ/7)

Comment: Your problem is this line: `if(approval.emailAddresses.filter(x => !!x.emailAddress).length)`. You've told it to include the whole `emailAddress` array as long as it contains at least one non-empty email address. So I don't think you need to filter `request.approvals`, but rather loop over it and filter the `emailAddress` array for each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not replacing `approval.emailAddresses` in your code - you should use:

```
approval.emailAddresses = approval.emailAddresses.filter(x => !!x.emailAddress);
```

See demo below:

```js
var request={approvals:[{type:'media',emailAddresses:[{emailAddress:'frank@gmail.com'},]},{type:'other',emailAddresses:[{emailAddress:''},]},{type:'scope',emailAddresses:[{emailAddress:'kelly@yahoo.com'},{emailAddress:''},]}]};
                        
var filterOutEmptyEmails = (approval) => {
   approval.emailAddresses = approval.emailAddresses.filter(x => !!x.emailAddress);
  if(approval.emailAddresses.length){
    return true;  
  }
}

var output = request.approvals.filter(filterOutEmptyEmails);

console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
```

**EDIT**:

Another proposal without mutating the input array - using `Array.prototype.reduce` to create a new array:

```js
var request={approvals:[{type:'media',emailAddresses:[{emailAddress:'frank@gmail.com'},]},{type:'other',emailAddresses:[{emailAddress:''},]},{type:'scope',emailAddresses:[{emailAddress:'kelly@yahoo.com'},{emailAddress:''},]}]};
                        

var output = request.approvals.reduce(function(p,c){
  // creates a shallow copy
  var elem = Object.assign({},c);
  // replaces the reference to request.approvals by the new array created by the filter
  elem.emailAddresses = elem.emailAddresses.filter(x => !!x.emailAddress);
  if(elem.emailAddresses.length != 0)
    p.push(elem);
  return p;
},[]);

// console.log(request.approvals);
console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

Comment: Ok so I see it works! Just a QQ: when filter returns `true` it will take account any mutations that happened inside of the loop?

Comment: Thats even more crazy cuz approval is a reference to the original object!

Comment: you want to do it without mutation?

Comment: Would it be possible to see that?  I'm just practicing so that would be awesome!

Comment: @MatthewHarwood check out the edit and let me know, thanks!

Comment: The non-mutating version of this answer is better than [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40880288/5069226) in regards of performance. See https://jsperf.com/fitering-nested-object-without-mutation

Comment: well, I agree with you... I should have used `map` function here :)

Answer (score 1):

Possible "non mutation" solution could be like this

```js
var request = {approvals: [{type: 'media',emailAddresses: [{emailAddress: 'frank@gmail.com'},]},{type: 'other',emailAddresses: [{emailAddress: ''},]},{type: 'scope', emailAddresses: [{emailAddress: 'kelly@yahoo.com'},{emailAddress: ''},]}]}

    const filterOutEmptyEmails = (approval) => {
      if(approval.emailAddresses.filter(x => !!x.emailAddress).length){
        return true;  
      }
      
    }
       
    const output = request.approvals.map(approval => {
      const filteredAproval = approval;
      filteredAproval.emailAddresses = approval.emailAddresses.filter(x => !!x.emailAddress);
      return filteredAproval
    }).filter(filterOutEmptyEmails);
    

    console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(request));
```

Answer (score 1):

Without mutation (with lots of ES6/7 sugar):

```
const filteredApprovals = request.approvals.reduce((acc, approval) => {
  const filteredEmailAddresses = approval.emailAddresses.filter(item => item.emailAddress);
  return (filteredEmailAddresses.length > 0) ? [...acc, { ...approval, emailAddresses: filteredEmailAddresses }] : acc;
}, []);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/free_soul/hndjbce3/